# Spark Java selectExpression not taking in method calls in caller

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have written a Spark Data Set which retrieves in data from a data source.
Now after that Data Set is retrieved in there are different operations to be triggered on them.

I have written the syntax as :

```
 Dataset<Row> lockupDetails = updatesDF2.withColumn("dummy", explode(lit(IntStream.range(0, no_of_periods).toArray())));

    lockupDetails = lockupDetails.selectExpr("*", "CAST(amount AS DOUBLE) / CAST(no_of_periods AS DOUBLE) AS lockup_amount");
    lockupDetails = lockupDetails.selectExpr("*","TIMESTAMP '" + "'add_months(date,no_of_periods)'" + "' as maturity_date");
```

The only problem in this code is inside selectExpression i am not able to call any inbuilt java methods in same file.

Does selectExpr in Spark does not takes in methods calls directly inside the argument so that i can dynamically generate the query.

Seems its not working in. Any heads up on this plz

Answer (score 0):

What you want is spark sql udf.

```
// Define and register a one-argument UDF
val plusOne = udf((x: Int) => x + 1)
spark.udf.register("plusOne", plusOne)
spark.sql("SELECT plusOne(5)").show()
// +------+
// |UDF(5)|
// +------+
// |     6|
// +------+
```

You can refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html